# Select multiple fields at different levels

Tags: json, jq, projection

I've a .json file that look like :

```
[
    {
        "network": "X.X.X.1",
        "defaultGateway": "X.X.X.X",
        "ipAddressTab": [
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.1",
                "foo2": "network",
                "foo3": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
            },
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.2",
                "foo2": "network",
                "foo3": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
            },
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.3",
                "foo2": "network",
                "foo3": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.4",
                "foo3": "available"
             },
             {   
                "foo1": "10.0.0.5",
                "foo3": "available"
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.6",
                "foo3": "available"
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.7",
                "foo3": "available"
             }
        ],
        "full": false,
        "id": "xxx"
    },
     {
        "network": "X.X.X.2",
        "defaultGateway": "X.X.X.X",
        "ipAddressTab": [
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.1",
                "foo2": "network",
                "foo3": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
            },
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.2",
                "foo2": "network",
                "foo3": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
            },
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.3",
                "foo2": "network",
                "foo3": "reserved",
                "foo4": null,
                "foo5": null,
                "foo6": null,
                "foo7": null,
                "foo8": null,
                "foo9": null,
                "foo10": null,
                "foo11": null
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.4",
                "foo3": "available"
             },
             {   
                "foo1": "10.0.0.5",
                "foo3": "available"
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.6",
                "foo3": "available"
             },
             {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.7",
                "foo3": "available"
             }
        ],
        "full": false,
        "id": "xxx"
    }
]
```

The first thing that I try that is to display each element like that :

```
cat myfile.txt | jq '.[]| {network: .network, ipAddressTab: .ipAddressTab}'
```

Each lines of the file xas displayed.

Now, I want to display some lines :

- network
- ipAddressTab
- foo1
- foo3

```
   {
        "network": "X.X.X.1",
        "ipAddressTab": [
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.1",
                "foo3": "reserved",
           
                "foo1": "10.0.0.2",
                "foo3": "reserved",
            
                "foo1": "10.0.0.3",
                "foo3": "reserved",
             
                "foo1": "10.0.0.4",
                "foo3": "available"
             
                "foo1": "10.0.0.5",
                "foo3": "available"
            
                "foo1": "10.0.0.6",
                "foo3": "available"
            
                "foo1": "10.0.0.7",
                "foo3": "available"
             }
        ],
        "full": false,
    },
     {
        "network": "X.X.X.2",
        "ipAddressTab": [
            {
                "foo1": "10.0.0.1",
                "foo3": "reserved",
           
                "foo1": "10.0.0.2",
                "foo3": "reserved",
          
                "foo1": "10.0.0.3",
                "foo3": "reserved",
            
                "foo1": "10.0.0.4",
                "foo3": "available"
             
                "foo1": "10.0.0.5",
                "foo3": "available"
          
                "foo1": "10.0.0.6",
                "foo3": "available"

                "foo1": "10.0.0.7",
                "foo3": "available"
             }
        ],
        "full": false,
    }
]
```

I've try something like :

```
cat myfile.txt | jq '.[]| {network: .network, ipAddressTab: .ipAddressTab(.foo1, .foo3)}'
cat myfile.txt | jq '.[]| {network: .network, ipAddressTab: .ipAddressTab[.foo1, .foo3]}'
```

But it doesn't work !

Some one to show me how to display each elements that I need ?

Thansk a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select the fields, then modify `ipAddressTab`.

```
map({network, ipAddressTab, full}
    | .ipAddressTab[] |= {foo1, foo3})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HjbVSbnHgi)</sup>