# Use jq nested array values

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a file, let's call it `heroes.json`, where part of the data is a nested array of object, `superpowers`:

```
[
  {
    "hero": "Superman",
    "id": "123",
    "realName": "Clark Kent",
    "age": "?",
    "superpowers": [
      {
        "name": "speed",
        "num": "1",
        "des": "Faster than a speeding bullet.",
        "value": "50"
      },
      {
        "name": "strength",
        "num": "2",
        "des": "More powerful than a locomotive.",
        "value": "100"
      }
    ],
    "weakness": "kryptonite"
  },
  {
    "hero": "Batman",
    "id": "456",
...
```

I want to select `hero` and `superpowers`, and keep only `name` and `des` keys within `superpowers`, like:

```
[
  {
    "hero": "Superman",
    "superpowers": [
      {
        "name": "speed",
        "des": "Faster than a speeding bullet."
      },
      {
        "name": "strength",
        "des": "More powerful than a locomotive."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "hero": "Batman",
    "superpowers": [
 ...
```

It wouldn't be hard to write an iterator to do this, but I want to try jq as I'm new to this tool and it seems useful to learn.

Answer (score 0):

So I experimented on [jqplay](https://jqplay.org) until it delivered the needed format. I don't know if it's optimal, but this worked:

`jq '[.[] | {hero, superpowers: [ .superpowers[] | {name, des} ] } ]'`

(A graphQL-like filter syntax would make this easier.)

Note: The output required for my json differs from what is mentioned in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277686/select-multiple-fields-at-different-levels), and I have avoided using map (iterator) in the solution. In other words, I'm not asking the same question, or presenting the same answer.

It would be helpful to know if my solution is optimal.

Comment: Re "*I'm not asking the same question*". False. The exact same solution (`map({hero, superpowers } | .superpowers[] |= {name, des})`) to the linked question can be used here

Comment: Re "*I'm not [...] presenting the same answer.*" True. Feel free to add your answer to the other question.